# composer installation on VPS with different domain hosting

Tags: php, centos, composer-php, cpanel

I am new to the composer, I have a VPS with several domains hosted. The VPS is the CentOS. Now I need to install the composer in order to meet several PHP systems' requirement. Now I have several questions about the installation.

1st, I have several systems, should I need to install several composers for each?

2nd, I have the root account to VPS and also have several cPanel accounts on it, owner and group are different to different cPanel accounts, when I install the composer, should I need to log in with different accounts and install it or only install by root?

3rd, where should I place the composer, any specific folder or the folder directly under the PHP system?

Hope someone can help to answer the above questions.

Best regards,

Kelvin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st - You need to install composer tool globally. This means that you need to install it once but you need to run `composer install` on each folder that has a composer.json file, in order to install its dependencies.

2nd - I am not sure how you server is organised regarding permissions, but I think installing it with root is enough.

3rd - I normally move and rename the composer.phar file to a location like `/usr/local/bin`.

--- Try doing these steps ---

Download composer (get instructions on link below)

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Make the phar executable:

`chmod a+x composer.phar`

Run this to move and rename it:

`mv ./composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

After this, you should be able to call composer from anywhere on your server. To test it, simply run: `composer`.

Now proceed to you app folder (where composer.json is located) and run: `composer install`